# Store Html Table Values in a javascript array and send it to laravel script using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, html-table

I have a html table.There are four columns of table named(itemName,itemprice and itemquantiy).I am adding the rows of table using a button through javacript and jquery.
Now i want to get the table rows as array and send it to laravel using ajax.
**My table is given below:**

```
<table id="orderDetailsTable" class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <!--<th scope="col">#</th>-->
                                            <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Item Unit Price</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Item Quantity</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Delete Item</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                </table>
```

Also tell me that how should my larvel php method;
thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jequery ajax request:

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           let convertedIntoArray = [];
           $("table#orderDetailsTable tr").each(function() {
               let rowDataArray = [];
               let actualData = $(this).find('td');
               if (actualData.length > 0) {
                   actualData.each(function() {
                       rowDataArray.push($(this).text());
                   });
                   convertedIntoArray.push(rowDataArray);
               }
           });

           $.post({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'url_to_your_method',
               data:{'table': convertedIntoArray},
           });
       });
   </script>
```

And in your method, get it from the request (table parameter)